# glibmm 2.4 invalid byte sequence in conversion input

Tags: c++, utf-8, glibmm

Trying to use Glibmm-2.4 to output Chinese returns "Invalid byte sequence in conversion input".

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <glibmm/ustring.h>
#include <glibmm/convert.h>

int main()
{
  Glib::ustring myUstring = "中"；
  try
  {
    std::cout << myUstring;
  }
  catch(Glib::ConvertError e)
  {
    std::cout << e.what();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?
Using Ubuntu 14.04.2 i386 LTS, g++, glibmm-2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An initialization of the locale is needed E.g. `std::locale::global(std::locale(""));` in order to use ustring and have it do the stream operator's implicit conversion correctly, otherwise characters outside of ASCII aren't converted correctly.

This is documented [here](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/classGlib_1_1ustring.html)